# Execute Select with tables with names with spaces in sql server from php and zend framework

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

i am using php 5.3, with zend framework... and i want to do a simple query to a table named "Entry Registry", as you can see with blank space between those words. In Sql management i can do the query like this "SELECT * FROM [Entry Registry]"... but when i want to do it in my model zend class, i am getting a error:

This is my code in my model class:

```
public function list()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM [Entry Registry]";
    try{
        $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
        return $result;
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Error: "  . $e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Table names with spaces are a bad idea for this reason, but to properly reference a table or object whose name contains spaces, in MySQL you would enclose the value in backticks.

So your code would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Entry Registry`";
```

This will correctly reference the table name with the space in it.